# Fringe closest to central maximum in YDSE

Tags: optics, interference, double-slit-experiment

The expression for fringe width in a classical YDSE is Wd/D(where W is the wavelength, d is the separation between slits and D is the distance between the slits and the screen).If YDSE is performed using white light, this expression suggests that a violet fringe would be formed closest to the central maximum. However, it is not so(says my textbook), and the reason is not clear. A friend told me that red would manifest first because it would be the least scattered, but I am not satisfied with this explanation, because of two reasons:

1. I don't think scattering would be a major factor here because we're talking about millimetres here, and it sounds counterintuitive that any significant difference in scattering would occur.
2. If scattering was the reason, the subsequent violet fringes should not be visible too. But it is not so.
   This has been bugging me for a few days now, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The intensity distribution given by
$$I=I(0)\cos^2(\alpha)\ \ \ \ \ \text{where}\ \ \alpha=\frac{\pi a \sin\theta}{\lambda}\approx \frac{ya\pi }{\lambda_0 s}$$
where $a$ is the distance between the slit.

You can plot this for different $\lambda$. It would look like [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8ddntrmgn7)

[image]

Now it's quite easy to add up colors. In the central, all colors have equal intensity so it would be white. After that the curve are almost varying same, it's hard for human eye to resolve but as this difference increase, one can see that there is repitative behavior.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering! Your figure and your graph suggest that the violet fringe must be the first one on either side of the central maximum. But that isn't what my book states.